# How can i filter items between 2 lists in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 list as follows:

```
   const allusers = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
       { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
       { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
       { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
     ];


    const user = [
       { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
       { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
     ];
```

I am trying to use grep, filter in javascript to return the values in allusers that are not in user.
How can i do this without using for loops ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending if you the property is set or not, if it is dynamic then you would have to iterate the key/value. Otherwise:

```
console.log(allusers.filter(a => user.findIndex(u => u.id === a.id && u.name === a.name && u.age === a.age && u.group === a.group) < 0));
```

Comment: assuming id's are unique, you could probably simplify the findIndex check to just comparing id's

Comment: @StephenCollins yup, that's true.. the question did not say anything about which key is unique.. as id is normally unique, the filter would be much simpler: console.log(allusers.filter(a => user.findIndex(u => u.id === a.id) < 0));

Comment: This gets pretty gnarly if you have to scale. Double-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your `user` array into a `Set` of IDs and then running a filter on `allusers`. The `Set` is important because you attain hash table efficiency - **O(1)** - for each filtering iteration. This will be much faster as you scale, otherwise you're doing a loop inside a loop.

```js
const allusers = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];


const user = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];

// Set for efficiency
const userSet = new Set(user.map(el => el.id));

const filtered = allusers.filter(user => !userSet.has(user.id));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: can I use multiple condition in the lambda expression user => !userSet.has(user.id). So user => !userSet.has(user.id) && user => !userSet.has(user.name) && user => !userSet.has(user.age) && user => !userSet.has(user.group)  ?

Comment: No, at that point it seems like you (probably) want an object. So it's possible you'll need to compare the other props too?

Comment: Can you help me understand this a bit better? You don't want to filter out a record just because it has the same user ID? It has to match every prop?

Comment: Yes every prop must be matched

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function and `some` function for that:

```js
const users = allusers.filter(au => user.some(u => /* here is your condition */ u.id === au.id ))
```

Comment: I have tried using this but get 'a' is undefined for some reason.

Comment: 'a'a is undefined look like some error out of the scope of your question, I reach this conclusion because there is no access to any variable called 'a' in the given code, could you send the rest of the code to get a better conclusion?

Comment: My apologies , I had the wrong variable. All good now. Thanks learnt something new . Everyday is a school day ;)